# String with Variables Concatenation Issue

Tags: c, json

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    char R_FPD[] = "+00393E33mm/go";
    char R_FPH[] = "+00393E33mm/go";
    char R_Vel[] = "+00393E33mm/go";
    char R_Tot[] = "+00393E33mm/go";
    char str_msg[] = "{"+"flow_rate_per_day"+":"+R_FPD+","+"flow_rate_per_hour"+":"+R_FPH+","+"velocity"+":"+R_Vel+","+"totalizer"+":"+R_Tot+"}";

    printf("%s", str_msg);
  
    return 0;
}
```

i want to make it like a json object but its not working

Comment: can you please convert this in to c

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C decay to pointers to their first elements and adding pointers is not defined in C standard.

The simplest way to concatenate string like this is using `sprintf` function. It works like `printf` but it prints into a C-string.

In your case the pattern could be following:

```
char str_msg[BIG_ENOUGH];
sprintf(str_msg, "{flow_rate_per_day:%s,flow_rate_per_hour:%s,velocity:%s,totalizer:%s}", R_FPD,R_FPH,R_Vel,R_Tot);
```

`BIG_ENOUGH` should be larger then the longest string that can be formed. `256` should be enough in your case.

Alternatively you can use `asprintf` function that will automatically allocated a buffer of the right size. Remember to use `free` when the buffer is no longer needed.

```
char *str_msg;
asprintf(&str_msg, "{flow_rate_per_day:%s,flow_rate_per_hour:%s,velocity:%s,totalizer:%s}", R_FPD,R_FPH,R_Vel,R_Tot);
... use str_msg

free(str_msg);
```

Comment: i used both solution but i got some errors

Comment: @Noman, what kind of errors?

Comment: sprint is not defined and asprintf is not a function  like this

Comment: @Norman it was sprintf, sorry for typo